# Is there software specialized in "puppet warp" animation?

Tags: adobe-photoshop

Photoshop CS5 comes with a feature called Puppet Warp.

I find it specially useful for a certain animation I'm making. Normally, I duplicate the layer, use puppet warp, done. Then duplicate again, and so on...

This is a bit frustrating because **I have to re-create the pins for every frame** (and you can't undo when you move a pin modifying the mesh, I think).

That's a shame, because this tool is great for my project.

I wonder if there is any other software specialized in puppet warp animation? Or, is there a way to not have to re-create the pins for every frame in Photoshop CS5?

Answer (score 4):

If you have After Effects, you can use the puppet tool to create your animation.

Here's Adobe's help page on it: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/aftereffects/cs/using/WS60CD3928-D380-481e-9B30-FBEE0D4E29CAa.html

I have not used it much, but I followed this tutorial when I played around with it a while ago: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9FKaPBAUBNY

Answer (score 1):

The way to avoid having to re-create the pins each time is by using a smart object, as explained in this [Adobe tutorial](http://tv.adobe.com/watch/russell-brown-at-photoshop-world-2011-orlando/creating-smart-object-animations-with-puppet-warp/).

Answer (score 0):

The best character animating software that comes to mind is [Toonboom Animate Pro](https://www.toonboom.com/products/animate-pro). It is similar to Flash (vector based), but designed specifically for animating and rigging characters.

Answer (score -1):

use puppet wrap on a smart object and the pins will remain available

Comment: I don't believe that you can change puppet-warp pin positions per each frame of an animation. If I'm mistaken, could you provide an example?